# Extract string in brackets using grep/sed/etc?

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I am trying to obtain a file location for PHP-FPM, using the following piped commands works:

```
ps aux | grep php-fpm  | grep master
```

Results:

```
root        80  0.0  0.6 334912 26072 ?        Ss   14:18   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/root/.symfony/php/2b1b88a9c9ed1cd796c66569d386096e96bbe2bc/fpm-7.3.33.ini)
```

However I still need to extract the file path between the brackets, can't quite figure it out, the input string is complaining about illegal tokens..

```
RESULT_FROM_ABOVE | grep -o '^[\(^.\)]*'
```

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

This doesn't work but should give the gist of the idea of what I am trying to achieve.

I need to escape the RESULT_FROM_ABOVE before the final grep I am trying to apply and I can't find any solution.

Thoughts?

Comment: Thanks for showing efforts, could you please post results of `ps aux | grep php-fpm ` command in your question that will help us to understand question better. Also please do edit sample output to make it more clear, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup a couple variables to simulate the `ps/grep/grep` (`pgg_out`) and `ps` (`ps_out`) output:

```
$ pgg_out='root 80 0.0 0.6 334912 26072 ? Ss 14:18 0:00 php-fpm: master process (/root/.symfony/php/2b1b88a9c9ed1cd796c66569d386096e96bbe2bc/fpm-7.3.33.ini)'
$ ps_out='
some stuff to ignore
root 80 0.0 0.6 334912 26072 ? Ss 14:18 0:00 php-fpm: master process (/root/.symfony/php/2b1b88a9c9ed1cd796c66569d386096e96bbe2bc/fpm-7.3.33.ini)
more stuff to ignore'
```

Piping the current `ps/grep/grep` output to `sed`:

```
$ echo "${pgg_out}" | sed -En 's/.*\((.*)\)/\1/p'
/root/.symfony/php/2b1b88a9c9ed1cd796c66569d386096e96bbe2bc/fpm-7.3.33.ini
```

Eliminating OP's current `grep` calls and piping the `ps` output to `awk`:

```
$ echo "${ps_out}" | awk -F'[()]' '/master/ && /php-fpm/ {print $2}'
/root/.symfony/php/2b1b88a9c9ed1cd796c66569d386096e96bbe2bc/fpm-7.3.33.ini
```

Comment: Wow this looks great. Thank you. I haven't had a chance to actually implement it but I'll accept the answer if I can get it to work. :) much appreciated